# Event Listener not removing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a problem involving the removal of an event listener from my document. Currently, I add the function to the document within my `drag_delta` function, and remove it in my `drag_stop` function. I'm trying to get the delta of the mouse dragging an image by using the `clientY` data, and comparing it to the `clientY` from the "on drag start" event. The current code executes up until the `drag_stop` function, ignoring it completely (I tried printing out the word "run" to see if its even acknowledging it). I wrote this in JSX since I'm using React:

```
//Creation of class, and initial state set 
var Knob = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
    return{season: 1};
  },
  
 drag_start: function(data){
   var startPos = data.clientY;
   console.log(startPos);
   document.addEventListener("mousemove",this.drag_delta);
 },
 
  drag_delta: function(data){
    console.log(data.clientY);
    this.setState({season: data.clientY});
    document.addEventListener("mouseup",this.drag_stop);
  },
  
  drag_stop: function(data){
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove",this.drag_stop);
    console.log("run"); 
  },
 
 render: function(){
    return(
           <div>
            <img src = "../style/img/wood-bg.png" />
             <img src ={ '../style/img/Seasons/sprites_cut/'+this.state.season+'.png'} ref = "season" onDragStart = {this.drag_start} />
           </div>
    );//Ed
  } //end render function
}); //end knob class

React.render(<Knob />, mountNode);
```

Comment: The issue is that drag events are different from mouse events. If you listen to `dragstart` then you have to listen to `dragover` and `dragend` (or `drop`) instead. `mouseover` and `mouseup` won't be fired. I suggest to read more about drag and drop on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Drag_and_drop. Or you prevent dragging, in which case you might be able to use the normal mouse events...

Comment: ok, so why does "mousemove" fire off and prints to the console on each movement of my mouse ? I fire off the "onDragStop" within the JSX, and then use "mouseup" within the React class as plain javascript.

Comment: I made a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5oohsd3q/. You are right, `mousemove` is triggered, but only *once*, not continuously. Releasing the mouse button doesn't trigger `mouseup` either. You can see that instead `mousemove` events continue to be triggered, until you clicked (`mousedown` + **`mouseup`**) again. At least that's the behavior I observe in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Right and thats my issue, I only need that clientY while the user is moving their mouse AND the mouse button is being held. Once released, the event listener SHOULD be removed and stop updating the clientY position.

Comment: And as I said, you likely have to listen to `dragover` and `dragend` instead. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, but that does not give me my desired result. I'm making a knob, and the knob needs to move in real time pending upon the pitch of the user's cursor (so if you drag the mouse up, it knob will turn upwards, and if you drag down, the pitch will go down). So if i listen for ondragstart and ondragend, it will delay the motion until the drag stops (but onmousemove will keep it going until the mouse stops moving)

Answer (score 0):

this is something to do with the event handling in browser, you bind the mouse up in the middle of mouse move, which means the event processing model won't updating until the current mouse moving event been completed. so when you finish move event(dragging and mouse up), then your new mouse up event will take effect, this is proved by Felix's observation.

event model is different from event model in OS(windows/mac, they can take effect at once ), event process only update when it's complete current process circle, what your changed for the event processing will only start take effect in the next circle of event processing.